# Best Approach for Implementing Video Selection from Gallery/Files in Ionic-React with Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

aim to provide users with the ability to select a video from their device gallery (on Android/iOS) or files (on PWA) within my application. The selected video should seamlessly integrate into the app interface.

Using `capacitor-community/file-opener`, I can only display the video fullscreen without embedding it, and this functionality doesn't work on PWA at all. And `capacitor/camera` does not support video handling.

Do I require a *cordova-plugin* to accomplish this functionality? Can I implement this using `capacitor/filesystem`? Or what approach do you suggest for achieving my goal?

Furthermore, is it necessary to duplicate the selected video, or can it remain in its original location?